# Bukkit - Check if a player sends a chat message containing an initialised double

Tags: java, methods, bukkit

Basically, I'm quite new to Java & Bukkit in general so please don't hate me if I'm doing something stupid. So basically the following code is my command base:

```
double numberEnd = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
double random = new Random().nextDouble();
double result = numberStart + (random * (numberEnd - numberStart));
theSender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "[Giveaway] + ChatColor.AQUA + "The winning number is " + result)
Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + (ChatColor.BOLD + "A giveaway has begun ranging from 0 - " + numberEnd));
Player winningPlayer;
```

So I want the plugin to realise when a player says the (result) and forward another broadcast saying that the (player) is the winner. Now, I don't quite know the exact approach but could I create the following method and call it in my code?

```
public void onPlayerChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent winningPlayer) {
    if (winningPlayer.getMessage().contains(result)) {
        Bukkit.broadcastMessage(winningPlayer.getPlayer() + ChatColor.GREEN + " has won!");
    }
}
```

Or is there an easier and more simple approach that I'm blindly missing?
Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: You mean you want to listen to player chat, check if player said a number and broadcast if he'll win?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

To listen to event first you need to register events on plugin enable

```
public void onEnable() {
    Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
    // Other code...
}
```

Make sure your class implements `Listener`. Here you registering all events, where first argument refers to `Listener` and second to your `Plugin`. Next you need to write your `onPlayerChat` method and add an `EventHandler` annotation to it to make this working.

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent winningPlayer) {
    if (winningPlayer.getMessage().contains(result)) {
        Bukkit.broadcastMessage(winningPlayer.getPlayer() + ChatColor.GREEN + " has won!");
    }
}
```

And of course you need in some ways to get the result from onPlayerChat method. You can just make `result` as global static variable.